# AWS SQS queue improve performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I tried implementing an AWS SQS Queue to minimise the database interaction from the backend server, but I am having issues with it.

- I have one consumer process that looks for messages from one SQS queue.
- A JSON message is placed in the SQS queue when Clients click on a button in a web interface.
- A backend job in the app server picks up the JSON message from the SQS queue, deletes the message from the queue and processes it.

To test the functionality, I implemented the logic for one client. It was running fine. However, when I added 3 more clients it was not working properly. I was able to see that the SQS queue was stuck up with 500 messages and the backend job was working properly reading from the queue.

Do I need to increase the number of backend jobs or increase the number of client SQS queues? Right now all the clients send the message to same queue.

How do I calculate the number of backend jobs required? Also, is there any setting to make SQS work faster?

Comment: We need more information - I've push hundreds of messages / second through SQS with no issues.  Code / details are needed.

Comment: What do you mean "stuck up with 500 message"? What exactly is not working here? Are you saying you couldn't add messages to the queue? The SQS queue just stores messages. There is no "work" being done by SQS so I don't understand what you mean about making it "work faster". You calculate the number of backend jobs required like this: If items in the queue aren't being processed as fast as you would want, add more workers.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the info.  Was wondering any limit on  number of messages it can store per second.    It appears like there is no limit  will add more worker threads and check it out.

Comment: There is only a throughput limit on the newer FIFO queues. If you are using a standard queue it should be able to handle virtually unlimited messages per second. But even the FIFO queues have a throughput of 300 messages per second which sounds much higher than what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details.  Is there are any metrics I can see for a period in aws console that can indicate me to increase the consumers?  Currently if clients are waiting I  will be increasing the consumers.  I am interested in knowing more about SWF.   It would be great if  you can share any good video link  how to creates swf  as most of videos  I have seen discussing theoretical part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having messages stored in a queue is good - in fact, that's the purpose of using a queue.

If your backend systems cannot consume messages at the rate that they are produced, the queue will act as a buffer to retain the messages until they can be processed. A good example is this AWS re:Invent presentation where a queue is shown with more than 200 million messages: [Building Elastic, High-Performance Systems with Amazon SQS and Amazon SNS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwLC5xmCZUs&t=1464)

If it is important to process the messages quickly, then **scale your consumers to match the rate of message production** (or faster, so you can consume backlog).

You mention that your process "picks up the JSON message from the SQS queue, deletes the message from the queue and processes it". Please note that best practice is to receive a message from the queue, process it and **then delete it** (after it is fully processed). This way, if your process fails, the message will automatically reappear on the queue after a defined invisibility period. This makes your application more resilient to failure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Will watch the video link.   Currently if clients are waiting I will be increasing the consumers  Is there are any metrics I can see for a period in aws console that can indicate me to increase the consumers?     I am interested in knowing more about SWF.   It would be great if  you can share any good video link  how to creates swf  as most of videos  I have seen discussing theoretical part?

Comment: Amazon CloudWatch has metrics on the number of messages in an Amazon SQS queue. These metrics can be used with Auto Scaling to automatically add capacity when the queue grows beyond a desired size. See: [Monitoring Amazon SQS using CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MonitorSQSwithCloudWatch.html) For Amazon Simple Workflow (SWF), take a look at the [AWS Reinvent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR3XyvHFYEg).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.  Thanks a lot